# Storing a tree structure in database, issue with cyclic references

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-ce

I'm developing a business management system where I have a list of customers organized as a tree using a hierarchy style of management:

```
Customer A
  -- Customer B
    -- Customer C
  -- Customer D
```

I have a table storing all customer data (name, contact info etc) and another table to map the relationships for this tree:

```
CREATE TABLE customer_tree
(
 "fromID" int, 
 "toID" int, 
 CONSTRAINT "fk_from_tree_customer" FOREIGN KEY (fromID) REFERENCES CustomerNode(id), 
 CONSTRAINT "fk_to_tree_customer" FOREIGN KEY (toID) REFERENCES CustomerNode(id), 
 "id" int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY)
```

Basically fromID is the parent node and toID is the ID of one of it's children, inserting a row for each child node.

Now, what I have a problem doing is keeping this table updated. Whenever I delete a customer I'd like the relationship in this table to be dropped as well. I tried using cascades using something like this to create the table:

```
 ... FOREIGN KEY (fromID) REFERENCES CustomerNode(id) ON DELETE CASCADE, 
 ... FOREIGN KEY (toID) REFERENCES CustomerNode(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

But the database will not allow me to create this table since it causes a cyclical reference that is now allowed. The tree structure is checked for cyclic nodes in code, so the actual cycles won't be an issue. However I'd like this relation to be dropped automatically whenever I delete a node.

Is there any easy way to accomplish this or work around the cyclic reference check?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Are you sure you want to delete customer C just because you deleted customer B?  Wouldn't Customer C become a direct child of Customer A?

Comment: you can use trigger on the customer table where you can delete the corrosponding entries from mapping table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create trigger for delete operation on CUSTOMER table.

In this trigger you can delete from customer_tree table where corrosponding customer is the same as Deleting customer.

you can build you trigger logic as below -

```
CREATE TRIGGER ON Customer
  BEFORE DELETE    
BEGIN
  DELETE FROM Customer_Tree Ct
   WHERE Fromid IN (SELECT Id FROM Deleted)
      OR Toid IN (SELECT Id FROM Deleted)
END
GO
```

I am actually not good in SQL Server, but I found this keywords from MSDN side.

[Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191300%28SQL.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, the answer is no. You have to do from code. You could investigate using the [hierarchyid](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677173.aspx) data type in SQL Server as an alternative.